# JTextArea - limit columns but now rows

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

In a custom cell renderer I use a `JTextArea` to display the nodes text. I want to limit the columns, so that the user doesn't have to scroll horizontally in the tree. Vertical Scroll is possible and the way to go.

How to limit the amount of columns and wrap the text automatically to the next line if it exceeds the limit?

Answer (score 5):

Try below...

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setColumns(10);
textArea.setRows(1);
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```